# PHP Bootstrap working perfectly on localhost but not working on VPS

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem with my Bootstrap/PHP code working perfectly on XAMPP  localhost but when I upload it to my /var/www folder with Apache and MySQL installed on the server, suddenly looks like .htaccess have problem. What should I do? Do I need to install something on my VPS like XAMPP? VPS has Linux Ubuntu Debian-7.0 (64 bit).

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Allow from all
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^password-reset/([^\/]+)(\/|)$  index.php?tab1=welcome&tab2=password_reset&user_id=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ index.php?tab1=admin [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^saved-posts/(.*)$ index.php?tab1=saved-posts [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^activated/(.*)$ index.php?tab1=activate&tab2=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([^\/]+)(\/|)$ index.php?tab1=search&query=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/([^\/]+)(\/|)$ index.php?tab1=app&app_id=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^messages/([^\/]+)(\/|)$  index.php?tab1=messages&user=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^terms/([^\/]+)(\/|)$  index.php?tab1=terms&type=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^setting/([^\/]+)(\/|)$  index.php?tab1=setting&user=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^page-setting/([^\/]+)(\/|)$  index.php?tab1=page-setting&page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^post/([^\/]+)(\/|)$ index.php?tab1=post&id=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^hashtag/([^\/]+)(\/|)$ index.php?tab1=hashtag&hash=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^follow-requests/(.*)$ index.php?tab1=follow-requests[NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([^\/]+)(\/|)$  index.php?tab1=timeline&u=$1&type=$2 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^p/([^\/]+)(\/|)$ index.php?tab1=page&p=$1 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(\/|)$  index.php?tab1=timeline&u=$1 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)(\/|)$  index.php?tab1=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: What does your apache config look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your Apache configuration, you will need to enable the `mod_rewrite` Apache module as well as set the `AllowOverride`option to `all`.

`mod_rewrite` is an Apache module that allows you to set rewrite rules for URLs.

`AllowOverride` is typically set to `none` by default, which will cause your htaccess file to be ignored by Apache. Make sure this is set to `all`. Then, restart your server. If everything was working fine locally, I am certain either or both of these are the issue.

Comment: `AllowOverride` is set to all, even `mod_rewrite` is active, but still http 500 error

Comment: Depends on your server